# Why fastlane plugins couldn't loaded after installation?

Tags: ios, ruby, fastlane

New to Fastlane setup, after install a plugin a warning message appears

```
[17:43:49]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile
[17:43:49]: It seems like you wanted to load some plugins, however they couldn't be loaded
[17:43:49]: Please follow the troubleshooting guide: https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/plugins-troubleshooting/
```

Checked the plugins troubleshooting guide and everything seems ok.

Answer (score 4):

The default generated Gemfile contains the code below.

```rb
plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '.', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

However, it assumes the `Pluginfile` is under the same project directory. If your `Pluginfile` is under `fastlane` folder. Change the code snippet to include the right path.

```rb
plugins_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'fastlane', 'Pluginfile')
eval_gemfile(plugins_path) if File.exist?(plugins_path)
```

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In my case, the correct path was already specified, but both lines were initially commented out. I resolved the issue by removing the '#' symbol from the beginning of each line.